# inserting into table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created table that consists of only foreign keys, it created successfully, but now I am inserting into the table and getting an error. ALL my tables before created successfully and works fine.

This is my code:

```
insert ALL 
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('512', 'null', '7113', '8115')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('511', 'null', '7111', '8111')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('512', 'null', '7111', '8114')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('514', 'ret001', '7113', '8113')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('516', 'null', '7115', '8112')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('515', 'ret002', '7114', '8113')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('517', 'null', '7113', '8115')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('511', 'null', '7112', '8118')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('513', 'null', '7111', '8117')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('512', 'null', '7115', '8116')
select * from DUAL;
select * from PRODUCT_BILLING;
```

This is my error:

```
Error starting at line : 147 in command -
insert ALL 
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('512', 'null', '7113', '8115')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('511', 'null', '7111', '8111')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('512', 'null', '7111', '8114')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('514', 'ret001', '7113', '8113')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('516', 'null', '7115', '8112')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('515', 'ret002', '7114', '8113')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('517', 'null', '7113', '8115')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('511', 'null', '7112', '8118')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('513', 'null', '7111', '8117')
    INTO PRODUCT_BILLING (DeliveryID, ReturnID, ProductID, BillID) VALUES
('512', 'null', '7115', '8116')
select * from DUAL
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C008513) violated - parent key not found

>>Query Run In:Query Result 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would speculate that the problem is `'null'`.  That seems like a very unusual value for a key.

If you want `NULL`, drop the single quotes.

I am guessing that the other values are also numbers -- they certainly look like numbers.  You should drop the single quotes for them too:

```
VALUES (512, null, 7113, 8115)
```

Of course, keep the single quotes if the values are really strings!  But only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: it worked when i removed the single quotes on the values and tested on a single row but does not work when inserting all rows at once

Comment: @Sileshan . . . Test each row individually.  One of them has key values that are not present in the other tables.